# Synchronize git workspace with another folder

Tags: git

Is there a standard way for synchronizing git workspace with another directory.
Suppose I have a directory that is under git version control. That directory is taken offsite and changes and done to it (files are changed, added and deleted). Then it is returned to my machine. How can I easily integrate all of these changes back into git.

If I were just to copy files over then new and changed files would be fine but information about removed files will be lost. Is there any way to easily do git rm on files that were removed while directory was outside of git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--work-tree` option of the [`git` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git) itself:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/your/other/directory status
git --work-tree=/path/to/your/other/directory add -A .
git checkout .
```

That will detect new, modified *and* removed files.
The last command is mentioned in [Mike Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2184226/mike-lippert)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032316/6309), to synchronize your own local working tree with the index you just updated.

That way, you are comparing:

- the content of "`another/directory`" (referenced by the `--work-tree` option)
- with the index of your current repo (where you are executing `git`)

Answer (score 5):

VonC's answer looks like the 1st part of what you want.

The `--work-tree` option is described on the [git(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)

However after running `git --work-tree=/path/to/your/other/directory add -A .` your index is different from your local (original) directory. To make the local directory match the index (that contains all the changes from the offline directory) run [`git checkout .`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/your/other/directory add -A .
git checkout .
```

Comment: +1. Good point. I have included the checkout step in my answer as well.